# Make the oscillator choice

Tags: pic, oscillator

I am using a PIC24FJ128GA010 and I need to make an oscillator choice. If I am not wrong, two main oscillator could be used 32KHz and 8 MHz. 
1. Do I really need 32KHz oscillator?
2. Element 14 website shows many 8MHz but the Microchip website advice to make a clever choice.

Could you please help me for this choice.

Comment: I should give more information about my circuit: I want to communicate with another MCU via SPI and control a motor with PWM. The answer given to my question seem really different. There is internal oscillator in the PIC24 but I think I need to add a 8MHz oscillator. I wish someone could explain me the difference between 2 oscillators with the same frequency (how to make the good choice).

Comment: Why do you think you need a crystal? The internal oscillator will be fine for SPI and motor control PWM.

Comment: I though I would need a crystal, how can I be sure the internal oscillator would be enough?

Comment: SPI is a synchronous protocol (it has a clock line) so precise timing is not critical, and PWM motor control relies on the average duty cycle so the timing is also not critical here either. I also added some more to the answer about crystal selection.

Answer (score 3):

You only need the 32kHz oscillator if you want to have a low speed oscillator present for uses like the RTC (Real Time Clock) peripheral, or low speed system clock operation. It is not required for operation of the microcontroller.

The primary oscillator crystal can be anything from 3.5MHz to 32MHz. If you want to use the PLL (phase locked loop) however, it must be between 3.5MHz and 8MHz. The phase locked loop is used to generate 4x the original frequency*, so you can use an 8MHz crystal and generate 4 * 8MHz = 32MHz for use as the system clock.
<sub>* note that other versions of the PIC24 have different PLLs onboard, this one is just the simple x4 version. See note 2 in table below</sub>

[image: PIC24 Oscillator]

Note that the PIC24 also has two internal oscillators, of 8MHz and 31kHz, so you can use it without an external crystal. The benefits of the crystal are better timing accuracy (needed for things like USB, UART, etc)

The part [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/39747d.pdf) is just an overview, for details you should refer to the [Family Reference Manual](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en024805) (halfway down the page) The [Oscillator](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39700c.pdf) section is relevant here.

**Selecting a crystal**

The PIC oscillator is designed for a parallel resonant (usually AT cut) crystal. Plenty of technical information on choosing the crystal and load capacitors is given in the Oscillator section above, read this thoroughly (particularly section 6.5 and 6.5.2.4).

Unless your applications timing is extremely demanding then the slight variations in temperature and frequency tolerance of different crystals won't matter much, if they do you would be better to look at using a TXCO or OXCO (temperature or oven controlled oscillator)
The frequency tolerance of a typical crystal varies between ±15 and ±100 ppm (parts per million) which is 0.01% and 0.0015%. To compare to the internal RC oscillator, the accuracy is given as ±2% at 25°C, and ±5% between -40°C and +85°C which equates to ±20000 and ±50000 ppm respectively (see part datasheet)
An excellent guide for oscillator design is the Microchip [AN588 - PIC oscillator design guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00588b.pdf). If you do a search on their site you will get other useful app notes such as:
[AN949 - Making your oscillator work](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/appnotes/00949a.pdf)
[AN849 - Basic PIC oscillator design](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00849a.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

8 MHz is a good start.  You don't need to use the 32kHz oscillator, but you can use it if you need low power operation, or you want to do timekeeping (using a watch crystal).

Answer (score 1):

Crystal Oscillators are most important element for microcontroller, Any microcontroller use Oscillator pulses for program execution.

**Have you read in any microcontroller tutorial about the instruction execution time cycle?** If you use 8MHz crystal instead of 4MHz than your controller execute your program instructions at double speed than 4MHz, Similarly 32MHz crystal has the most fastest time than all other crystal options.

If you are making any project that deals with **ADC**, **I2C**, **LCD**, **USB**, **LAN / Ethernet** and or **UART** communication from the same controller than it is recommended to use higher value Crystal, However you may get same results with simply 8MHz crystal with slow time which is very common among beginners.

**So Why 32KHz crystal is their?** It is necessary if you are making any Real Time Clock (RTC) or dealing with RTC based circuits, Because from 32KHz crystal you will get one second accurate pulse, that you may use for making Clocks or any Timing Function Circuits.

In some microcontroller their are some extra features also present, You can use higher value Crystal on Oscillator Pins as well as 32KHz crystal on other pins for microcontroller internal oscillator calibrations, which is a advance level

Answer (score 0):

The choice between 32 kHz and and 8 MHz will depend on your **performance requirements** and **power requirements**. High performance and low-power don't go well together: you want a fast clock to perform the required actions in time, but power consumption is nearly linear with clock frequency. A microcontroller will typically need ten times more power at 10 MHz than at 1 MHz.

So go for **32 kHz** if you can afford it. Also then you have two options, depending on the required timing precision: the internal 31 kHz RC oscillator is cheap, because it doesn't need external components, but is not accurate enough for a real-time clock, for instance. If you need more accurate timing you'll need a 32.768 kHz crystal. Those are still inexpensive. Both solutions give you a low power consumption.

Go for **8 MHz** if you need the performance. That can be because you have to sample an analog signal at a high sample rate and clock this data at several Mbps though SPI, for instance. Again you have the choice between an internal 8 MHz RC oscillator, which is OK if timing precision isn't a premium. Otherwise use an 8 MHz crystal. You can still increase the clock frequency using the on-chip PLL.

**Further reading**
[PIC24F Family Reference Manual, Sect. 06 Oscillator](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39700a.pdf)
[PIC24FJ128GA010 Family Data Sheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/39747d.pdf)